# Mean.IO Stack - Error Connecting to database: { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]

Tags: mongodb, mean.io

I am setting up Mean.IO on my Mac OS X El Capitan Machine.  I have gotten Mean.IO up successfully, but when it asks me to set up an admin, it gives me the following error:

```
#############################################

  Congratulations you have mean.io installed.

Before you install the dependencies and fire up the server we can help you with setting up your first admin user.
? Please provide your username so we can create your first admin user: **********
    Error Connecting to database: { [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017' }
*******-MBP-2:~ **********$
```

I haven't had experience setting up this stack before, so not sure why Mongo is acting up.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application cannot establish a connection to the MongoDB database because the database server is not running. You can open another terminal window and start the server with:

```
sudo mongod
```

Comment: Even after running the database, I am still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

@user1072337

try changing the internet connection even I faced the same issue while connecting my simple node.js rest api app to mongodb server(mlab)

**but eventually found out it was due to the wifi security and limited access**

**solution try connecting using your mobile hotspot.**
worked for me.